# Nextjs cannot read the env when is deployed to the Azure Container App

Tags: azure, google-maps, next.js, environment-variables, azure-container-apps

I'm using NextJS for my project. It's working well in my local but when i deployed it to the Azure Container App, my next app can't find the env. I used the prefix NEXT_PUBLIC_ for my env and also tried to set the env in the build time with Dockerfile and application enviroment. But it's still not working. Do anyone know the solution to fix it?

Thank

Comment: hi could you share the relevant part of your nextjs project and also how you dpeloy the container app ? az cli / bicep / something else ?

Comment: Hi @Thomas. I see that its only occurs when i set the NODE_ENV to the production. Its working well with other NODE_ENV. Im using devops azure to deploy (build image and push to the Azure registries -> deploy to the container app)

Comment: Thanks but it's not that helpful to debug / reproduce your issue. Do you have some code sample we could try ? to reproduce your issue ?\

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a start, the community recommends that you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase your chances of getting help and solving your issue. It is also best that you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can check and see what might have caused your issue.